# In a generic class, how to create a Nullable<T> property if T is non-nullable?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, blazor, nullable

I have the following class that can accept generally numeric or `string` types:

```cs
public class MdSlider<TValue> where TValue: IConvertible, IEquatable<TValue>
{
    TValue? Value { get; set; }
    TValue? Min { get; set; }
    TValue? Max { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

However I just realized if user create a `MdSlider<double>` for example, all those three properties are `double` and not `double?` and they have values of `0` by default instead of `null`. My app requires null value when user does not set it.

- If I add `struct` constraint, `string` is not accepted anymore.
- I cannot declare a separate `MdSlider` for `string` because this is in Blazor and the component name must be unique (`MdSlider<TValue>` and `MdSlider` is considered the same) and I do not want to make a distinct `MdSliderString` for example.

Is it possible to declare a generic type parameter and force a `Nullable` on the property if it's non-nullable? Any other solution I can make this work for Blazor components?

Comment: In short - no, without generic constraint. See the duplicate. As a workaround you can create 2 versions - one for structs and one for reference types.

Comment: You are probably right. I checked the Microsoft official project to see how they deal with it (they also have generic Blazor controls). So they have all the nullable properties (`Min`, `Max` etc) to be `string` instead of `T` and only the `Value` (which is always present) is `T`.

Comment: Your question suggests `MdSlider` is a slider Blazor component and `Value`, `Min` and `Max` are really Parameters for that component.  If so, get the question opened and I'll try and demonstrate how and why this can be made to work in the component context.  I need more space than a comment!

Comment: Done.  See the answer below which may provide you with the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer demos how this works with Blazor components:

Here's my demo `Slider.razor`

```cs
@typeparam TValue

<input type="range" @bind:get="Value" @bind:set="SetValue" class="form-range" min="@Min" max="@Max" id="customRange2">


@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TValue? Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TValue? Min { get; set; }

    private async Task SetValue(TValue? value)
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And the demo `Index` using both a nullable string and a [non nullable] double.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="mb-3">
    <Slider Max="_stringMax" Min="_stringMin" @bind-Value="_stringValue" />
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <Slider Max="_max" Min="_min" @bind-Value="_value" />
</div>



<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>String Value : @_stringValue</pre>
    <pre>Value : @_value</pre>
</div>

@code {
    string? _stringMax = "10";
    string? _stringMin = "-10";
    string? _stringValue;

    double _max = 10;
    double _min = -10;
    double _value;
}
```

The reason why this works is because there's no tight coupling between `Value` in the child and the value supplied in the component definition.  The value supplied in the parent is defined in the `ParameterView` passed to the child component in `ParametersSetAsync`.

How this is applied to the child component is up to the child: the normal way uses Reflection and handles the type conversion gracefully.

```
    public virtual Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
```

You can do it manually - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually.

##### Additional Version of Slider Component

As I'm not sure exactly what you want, here's a version of the slider control that demonstrates some fairly advances techniques you can use to build whatever real component you need.

`SetParametersAsync` does all the work in handling the incoming content and converts everything to strings for use in the Input.

`SetValue` does the conversion from the string returned from the input to `TValue` using the `BindConverter` utility.

`BuildRenderTree` uses the render tree builder to build out the content with logic to control what needs to be included.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SO77161463.Pages;

public class MySlider<TValue> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TValue? Max { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TValue? Min { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? CssClass { get; set; } = "form-range";

    private string? _value;
    private string? _max;
    private string? _min;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            switch (parameter.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Value):
                    if (parameter.Value is null)
                    {
                        _value = null;
                        this.Value = default;
                        break;
                    }
                    _value = parameter.Value.ToString();
                    this.Value = (TValue)parameter.Value;
                    break;
 
                case nameof(Max):
                    if (parameter.Value is null)
                    {
                        _max = null;
                        this.Max = default;
                        break;
                    }
                    _max = parameter.Value.ToString();
                    this.Max = (TValue)parameter.Value;
                    break;

                case nameof(Min):
                    if (parameter.Value is null)
                    {
                        _min = null;
                        this.Min = default;
                        break;
                    }
                    this.Min = (TValue)parameter.Value;
                    _min = parameter.Value.ToString();
                    break;

                case nameof(CssClass):
                    this.CssClass = parameter.Value?.ToString() ?? null;
                    break;

                case nameof(ValueChanged):
                    if (parameter.Value is not null)
                        ValueChanged = (EventCallback<TValue?>)parameter.Value;
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown parameter: {parameter.Name}");
            }
        }

        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    private async Task SetValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(e.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TValue? result))
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(result);
        else
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(default(TValue));
    }


    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(1, "input");
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "type", "range");
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", _value);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "class", this.CssClass);

        if (_max is not null)
            builder.AddAttribute(5, "max", _max);

        if (_min is not null)
            builder.AddAttribute(6, "min", _min);

        builder.AddAttribute(7, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(this, SetValue));

        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

Note that the `Parameters` are just used as a messenger service to get values into the component.

Comment: Hi sorry I won't be able to test it yet for the next few days but could you clarify that in case users **do not** provide `Min` or `Max` value, that attribute is not printed (this is important)? If `TValue` is `double`, then Max will default to 0 and cannot be null and therefore being printed out when user does not provide it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "printed".

Comment: See revised answer and the commentary.

Comment: Hi, again sorry I won't have access to an IDE to test in the next few days. What I meant by "printing" is that the resulted HTML should not have that attribute if it's null. For example: `<MdSlider Value="10" />` should only prints `<md-slider value="10"></md-slider>` and NOT `<md-slider value="10" max="0" />` if Blazor developer who use `MdSlider` does not give `Max` value (which is the problem I am having, because it causes the `<md-slider>` to malfunction, `<md-slider>` is the equivalent to `input` in your case). Again, this is just explaining, I don't know if you answer works or not yet.

Comment: I assume this is Material Design.  The second component shows you how to add or not add attributes based on their values.  You can do it in Razor, but there's an awful lot of markup duplication, so in this case the `RenderTreeBuilder` method seems the more appropriate way.  Anyway, hopefully some pointers on how to code the real one.

Comment: Thanks, right now I follow the approach of the MS team at [Fluent Blazor](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor). Their `Value` (which is mandatory in a way) is of `TValue?` type but their optional `Max`, `Min` etc are `string?`. This way, when a value is `null` (user does not provide it), Blazor does not print out that attribute. Make sense though because you don't really need to bind it so them not being `TValue` is not really a problem.